# why my JSON deserializeUntyped giving me Exception

Tags: apex, rest-api, json, map

I'm creating a new REST API in salesforce and receiving the below JSON in Restrequest string

```
{"event_source":"","event_time":"2022-05-25 08:12:40.151","event_value":"{\"ad\":\"\",\"media_source\":\"restricted\"}"}
```

and when I try to deserialize in map I'm getting below error

DEBUG|Exception : Invalid conversion from runtime type String to Map

I'm using this conversation

```
Map<String, Object> params = (Map<String, Object>)System.JSON.deserializeUntyped(RestContext.request.requestBody.toString());
Map<String, Object> eventVal = (Map<String, Object>)params.get('event_value');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decoded parameter is JSON, so you have to deserialize again:

```
Map<String, Object> params = (Map<String, Object>)System.JSON.deserializeUntyped(
  RestContext.request.requestBody.toString()
);
Map<String, Object> eventVal = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUnTyped(
  (String)params.get('event_value')
);
```

If you can, I'd get that payload changed to something more "normal."

Comment: You nailed sfdcfox. I missed that the answer could be to parse a JSON inside of a JSON.

Answer (score 3):

That is because `event_value` is escaped inside of a string. Meaning it starts with quotes, and all quotes inside are escaped with a backslash:

```
{
  "event_source": "",
  "event_time": "2022-05-25 08:12:40.151",
  "event_value": "{\"ad\":\"\",\"media_source\":\"restricted\"}"
}
```

To parse differently, you need JSON changed in the source or modified by your code, but what seems to be expected is something around these lines:

```
{
  "event_source": "",
  "event_time": "2022-05-25 08:12:40.151",
  "event_value": {
    "ad": "",
    "media_source": "restricted"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your describe JSON working perfectly fine but when I try to String transformedJSON = jsonIpt.replaceALL('/',''); .....It;s still getting Exception...